# Why PDO queries are not working on server?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, md5

I have just uploaded my local project to server but PDO queries are not working in LIVE server. It's working fine on local. I thought PDO might not be installed on server so i ran the below script

PHP version in server is `PHP Version 5.3.3`, Linux server

```
<?php
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO unavailable';
}else{
    echo 'pdo is installed';
}
?>
```

Connection.php:

```
<?php
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname12', 'myusername', 'password');
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        exit('Database Error');
    }

?>
```

Login:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../includes/connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])){
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = md5($_POST['user_password']);

    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
        $error = 'All fields are required!';
    }else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);
        $query->execute();
        //var_dump($query);exit;
        $num = $query->rowCount();

        if ($num == 1) {
            // User correct details let's log him in
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            $error = 'Incorrect Details';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

By entering correct credentials the login is showing `incorrect details always` + For debugging i bypassed the login and entered dashboard where we are fetching articles from DB but nothing was there. And in database we have many entries.

Comment: Check that your `$query->execute()` worked, because you're not doing that currently. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: (And stop using MD5 for passwords! It's dangerous! Use http://php.net/password_hash.)

Comment: @ceejayoz i added `        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
        if (!$query) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
        }
` still getting incorrect details

Comment: `if(!$query)` will never fire, because `$query` exists, and I've no idea why you're mucking around with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.

Comment: @ceejayoz this returns  `echo $pdo->errorInfo();`
array nothing else?

Comment: There's a reason the `PDO::errorInfo` docs show `print_r` in the example, not `echo`. You can't `echo` an array, and `errorInfo` returns one. Please read and understand the docs you've been linked to instead of attempting random code.

Comment: I think you have an error with binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know if this is a bug or not, but adding `dbname=dbname12` to below line everything starts working!

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname=dbname12', 'myusername', 'password');
```

Locally it was working fine with the below code but on server when I added `dbname` then queries started working.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname12', 'myusername', 'password');
```

Comment: Locally you may or may not need to do `dbname=dbname12` and can just leave it as `dbname12` however it's the correct way and good practice to always do it how it's specified here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php